# Get the number of retained users using User table and API logs on Rails Console

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, database

I want to get the number of retained users for next 24-48 hours after their sign-up using our User table and API logs, specifically `created_at` and `'user_id'` in User table and logs like `['user_id', 'resquest_time']` for example `[238544, "2015-08-10T11:59:59+09:00"]`

Like: `User.where(:created_at => "2015-08-06".."2015-08-07".where(:id => SOMETHING MAGICAL).count`

In Something magical I want to add a condition that their IDs are included in the log after 24 hours and before 48 hours from their each created_at.

I did this by code:

```
time = "2015-08-07".."2015-8-10"
#result = [...] this is logs hash

User.where(:created_at => time).each do |u|
    result.each do |l|
        next if l.nil?
        if u.id == l[0]
            if u.created_at + 1.day <= Time.parse(l[1]) && u.created_at + 2.days >= Time.parse(l[1])
                num_retained += 1
                break
            end
        end
    end
end
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not too sure what your question is about, as you yourself have already a code that could answer your question. Specifically now, I wanted to ask what might be missing in your code above? or are you asking how to get the `result` values from your logs hash? If you're asking about how to get the `result` values, please provide first a sample api log file (if you're getting logs data from a file) or a sample log record (if you're getting logs data from db)